# Python 3 type is both an object and class?

Tags: python, metaclass

I am reading **Learning python**. Regarding metaclass, the book said type is an object and also is itself class. I am trying to search python doc online but don't see any similar description. Can someone point me any official doc?

Thinking a bit more on this statement that type is both object and class, I think it makes sense.

The reasons are as following.

1. type is callable, seeing [type()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type). Then it should be either a function or object which has implemented **call**
2. any object is instanced from a class. Given it's in the top hierarchy, it makes sense that its class is itself.

My second question is that metaclass is subclass of type class? Is it still true that metaclass is also an instance of type object/class? Because when Metaclass(...) is invoked, type.**call** is invoked then Metaclass must be instance of type

Comment: Please don't ask two separate questions at the same time. One concern per question, please.

Comment: Your question is too broad for this site; please ask only one question per post.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of/addressed in answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python

Comment: type is a type, but you can't replicate that trick in Python code directly.  It's a sleight-of-hand in the implementation.

Comment: Reading this should cover everything in your question: [What are metaclasses in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Even as a callable, `type` has two completely different uses. `type` with one parameter *returns* the class of an objecdt, while `type` with 3 arguments *creates* a new class, which is itself an object of the class `type`.

Of course, by that logic, `type` itself could be an instance of another class, and that class an instance of another class. But this had to stop somewhere. The design choice is that it stops there. There is no meta-metaclass. `type(type)` returns `type`. This is magic, in the sense that it does not follow from any logical rules, it is just specially implemented.